# how convert my chart from current from to another in python data science?

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory, graph-data-science, graphplot

This is my dataframe:
[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGryx.png)

I have generated this type of plot:
[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjyV9.png)

I have wanted this type of plot:
[this is generated in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp4uT.png)
what will be code snippet for it?

Comment: Hi. This is not a code wiring service. Please provide the code you have written when you honestly tried to fulfill your retirement. Moreover please read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and subsequent help links where you will learn that you should provide your references embedded in the question and not in links, and as text in code blocks rather than images as far as possible. Thanks

Comment: @Zeitounator, i will keep your suggestion in mind next time, sorry for inconvienece.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to transpose the dataframe.

```
df.T.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]